# karma-jasmine-html-reporter always shows errors when clicking on a test

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I have a single unit test:

```
describe("TestSuite", () {
    it("should test true", function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The test passes fine as expected but when I click on it on the generated html, I always see errors like below.  I have no idea why these errors are shown and do not know what I may be doing wrong.  I am using **karma-jasmine-html-reporter 2.0.0**.

[image]

Is there some configuration I am missing or is my unit test not written correctly?